# How determine if a Cloud Firestore query is false using Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to check if a cloud firestore query does not return a document or a set of documents. Here is my code:

```
if(Firestore.instance.collection("Categories").where("userEmail", isEqualTo: "${user?.email}").where("category_title", isEqualTo: categoryName.text).getDocuments() == null){
  print("Query is False");
}
```

With the code above, I am not getting the output I want.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to check.  What does it mean that a query is "false"?  Are you checking for errors?  For presence of documents in the result set?  Values in those documents?  Please edit the question to be specific.

Comment: Hi, I have edited my question. Please have a look. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to await the call but then you can use `length` property to check if there is any result

```
var result = await Firestore.instance.collection("Categories")
    .where("userEmail", isEqualTo: "${user?.email}")
    .where("category_title", isEqualTo: categoryName.text)
    .getDocuments()

if (result.documents.length == 0) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: The problem is that `getDocuments` returns a `QuerySnapshot` and not the actual List of Documents. To get this you have to call the `documents` getter on `result`. If the error still shows the `Future<QuerySnapshot>` than you might have missed the `await` before the Firestore call.

Comment: Yes, thanks @NiklasLehnfeld. Added `documents`, await was already there.